# file_get_contents plus file_exists (inside the file which gets called)

Tags: file-get-contents, file-exists

I have many different templates for sending emails! 
So I made a php file (lets call it send.php) which I want to "call" with file_get_contents and some parameters (which decide which template should be used) from another File like finish.php!

The different Paths:

1. templates ("/phpmailer/templates/")
2. send.php ("/phpmailer/send.php")
3. finish.php ("/courses/finish.php")

The working Link itself looks something like this:

```
http://www.myadress.at/phpmailer/send.php?template=booking&email=bla@bla.at&name=Christopher
```

Inside the send.php I check if the template exists, if YES then the Mail will be sent!

```
if (file_exists(dirname(__FILE__)."/templates/".$template.".php") AND isset($email)) {

  $mail->msgHTML(file_get_contents('https://www.myadress.at/phpmailer/templates/'.$template.'.php?'.$parameter.''), dirname(__FILE__));

  if (!$mail->send()) {
      echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
  } else {
      echo "Message sent!";
  }

} 
else 
{
  ERROR
}
```

Now when somebody books a course or something, after filling out the signup-form, I want to send an Confirmation Email from the file, the person is landing after the form (finish.php)

My finish.php file hast just a file_get_contents with the Path to my send.php file:

```
$sendmail= file_get_contents("https://www.myadress.at/phpmailer/send.php?template=booking-confirmation&email=".urlencode($email)."");
```

Now the problem is, when trying to use it from finish.php with file_get_contents, he says the Template doesnt exist... When copying the same link to firefox, everything works.. The name of the template is right!

I've tried the following things:

```
(file_exists(dirname(__FILE__)."/templates/".$template.".php") - with dirname
(file_exists("/templates/".$template.".php") - the normal path
(file_exists("/phpmailer/templates/".$template.".php") - full path
(file_exists("http://www.myadress.at/phpmailer/templates/".$template.".php") - normal url
```

Pleaaase help me ^^ Maybe this isnt possible haha

Answer (score 0):

Okay, now everything works fine!

The problem was caused by either by some spaces in the url or because I didn't urlencode every single variable..

ahhhh so many time!